# Get url to which bitly short-url redirects with HTTP Request using Java

Tags: java, httprequest, unirest

I have short-url

```
bit.ly/18SuUzJ
```

that leads to

```
stackoverflow.com/
```

Do you know how to get that url using HTTP Request with Java?
I added Unirest to maven dependencies and tried sth like:

```
    HttpResponse<String> response = Unirest.get("bit.ly/18SuUzJ").asObject(String.class);
    System.out.println(response.getBody());
```

but I get whole structure of that page, not only url .
How to get only url that would work for other bitly short-urls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
final String link = "bit.ly/18SuUzJ";
final URL url = new URL(link);
final HttpURLConnection urlConnection = 
(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);

final String location = 
urlConnection.getHeaderField("location");
System.out.println(location);
```

location will print the complete URL.